# Is there a method to track gps of another iphone if both the iphone is having application installed?

Tags: iphone, ios5, gps, xcode4.3

I am new to iphone development.I want to know that is there a framework or method to get the gps location of another iphone if the application is installed in both the iphone.
If there is any method can u please help me to sort out this 
thanks in advance?

Comment: Thank God, no.  That would be a HUGE security problem.  If you want users to be able to share location, they have to opt in to use location services in the app, and then the app would have send coordinates to a server or directly to another phone, neither of which is especially trivial.

Comment: Does anybody know of such an app though?  We are developing a web application (not a native app) which deals with fleet management.  So we want the iPad to push its coordinates to a central server so that we can access their location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with James, thank god it is not open in that anyone can see where anyone is via a single method, but I did create a solution that does this as a test app and it was not to difficult.

The frameworks that I used are Core Location to get the GPS coordinates, Foundation Framework to share the information with a web service using NSURLConnection, MapKit to map the coordinates, and the open source SBJson encoder/decoder.

I then created a PHP web service that enabled users of the app to register and choose who they would share their location with.

Then once per minute each instance of the app that is active would send its coordinates to the web service and then download any coordinates of other devices that it is allowed to see.

If I published this app, I would probably provide an option to chose the update frequency to conserve battery life.

Two free apps that also do this, that were created by Apple, are the Find Friends and Find iPhone apps.

If you are interested in creating something like this, check out the LocateMe sample code at developer.apple.com.